# How to Load a page in a dynamically generated iFrame when a link is clicked like a lightbox in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, iframe, hyperlink, lightbox

I have a list of links eg :

```
<ul> 
<li><a href="http://google.com">Link1</a></li>
<li><a href="http://example.com">Link2</a></li>
<li><a href="http://example.com/sdf">Link3</a></li>
</ul>
```

When a link is clicked, a iFrame should be generated in the middle of the screen loading the page like a lightbox.

How to do this with jQuery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('a').bind('click', function(e){
    $('<iframe/>', {
       src:   $(this).attr('href'),
       class: 'myiframe',
       css:   {
           position: 'absolute',
           width:    '200px',
           height:   '200px',
           top:      window.innerHeight / 2 + 300,
           left:     window.innerWidth / 2 + 300
       }          
    }).appendTo(document.body);

    return(false);
});

$(document.body).bind('keydown', function(e){
  if(e.which === 27)
     $('.myiframe').remove();
});
});​
```

I poorly calculated the top/left coordinates there, you might want to replace that with a css class anyway. Use `class: "classname"` for that within creation.

References: [.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), .[attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), [.appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/), [jQuery Core](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
// we only want to use a single iframe:
var $iframe = $("<iframe>").css({
  width: '100%', 
  height: '10em'
  // we can set more css properties to make it positioned where we want, etc...
});
$("a").click(function() {
   // stick it at the end of the <body> tag, and set its src property
   $iframe.appendTo('body').attr('src',this.href);
   return false;
});
```

Of course for anything other than a demo, you'll want a more specific selector than `a` which will find every link, something like `.myLinks a` and add `class='mylinks'` to the `<ul>` is probably the best option.  You also have more options for styling the `<iframe>` using css properties/classes.

[Demo on jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/SSsQN/)

Comment: Hey thank you, jsfiddle is really good. Thanks for you code and intro to jsfiddle

Comment: @Aakash Chakravarthy - No problem - also, you can mark an answer as "accepted" by clicking on the checkbox below the posts score.